# Vim: NERD_tree Plugin. Need help understanding a bloggers .vimrc addition to streamline this plugin

Tags: vim

So I'm basically a beginner when it comes to Vim, nonetheless I do know the basic things (open files, edit, move around, basic grep, .vimrc, etc)

I would submit this link first

http://weblog.jamisbuck.org/2008/11/17/vim-follow-up

If you scroll down to where it says "NERD___tree", it explains what it is and gives a link to the home page. I have already gotten NERD_tree installed, so far so good.

Only thing is, this guy (JamisBuck) adds a line to the .vimrc file to streamline it's usage (I'm guessing to toggle between NERD_tree and the actual file, because as far as I can tell, there is no quick way to do it other than typing in:

```
:NERDTree
```

Every time which is less than desirable. The follwing is the code he adds to the .vimrc file:

```
map <leader>d :execute 'NERDTreeToggle ' . getcwd()<CR>
```

He doesn't explain exactly what is is and/or how to use it, so If someone could give me a short explanation and/or point me towards a resource to learn more about this, that would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd say `:help leader` will give you what you need,  is an anti-slash by default.

Thus, `map <leader>d` will be launched when you do `\d`.

Comment: I don't understand your summation of your answer, but your actual answer:

    \d

Is the correct answer. Thanks. I would give you an upvote but I don't have enough rep.

Answer (score 5):

According to the [vim documentation](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/map.html), the

```
<Leader>
```

Is a special variable that is replaced with the value of "mapleader" at the time the mapping is defined. So:

```
map <leader>d :execute 'NERDTreeToggle ' . getcwd()<CR>
```

Is mapping the mapleader and "d" to the toggle. If you look at the page you linked, earlier in the page he says:

```
I’ve got my <Leader> character (:h mapleader) mapped to the comma 
(since it’s easier to reach than the backspace character).

let mapleader = ","
```

So the toggle should be ",d" as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 4):

In addition to what others have said (d mapped to the command), the command, itself:

```
:execute 'NERDTreeToggle ' . getcwd()<CR>
```

Is simply executing the NERDTreeToggle command with the first argument as the current working directory. The  at the end is a carriage return, and is just simulating a press of the enter key.

This means that when NERD tree opens, it will be in the current working directory.